# Retrieve child value from firebase to an array to use in a table view cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, scope

I am retrieving **almondRate** from Snapshot to an array **cakeRates**in this class. but there is error -- use of unresolved identifier **almondRate**. How can i get the value of **almondRate** from snapshot to put in an array.
I think this may the problem of scope of a variable, help me to overcome this please!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var cakeTableView: UITableView!

var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

var  cakeEngNames = ["almond Cake", "Jelly Cake"]
var  cakeUrNames = ["badam cake", "jeli ka cake"]
var cakeImages = [UIImage(named: "Maru")!, UIImage(named: "spices")!]
var  cakeRates = ["\(almondRate)", "45"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Karachi").child("Bakery").child("Cake").child("Almond_Cake")
    AlmondSnap.observeSingleEvent(
        of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let almondRate = snapshot.value as! String
            self.cakeRates.append(almondRate)
            print("\(almondRate)")
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cakeEngNames.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.cakeImage.image = cakeImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.cakeEngLabs.text = cakeEngNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.cakeUrLabs.text = cakeUrNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.cakeRateLabs.text = cakeRates[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

[image]

**Update: Retrieve all child values of "cake" to cakeRateLabs**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var cakeTableView: UITableView!

var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


struct Cake {
    let cakeEngNames: String
    let cakeUrNames: String
    let cakeImages: UIImage
    var cakeRates: String
}


var cakes = [Cake(cakeEngNames: "almond Cake", cakeUrNames: "badam cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"Maru")!, cakeRates: ""),

             Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: ""),

             Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: ""),

             Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrNames: "jeli ka cake", cakeImages: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRates: "")]




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Karachi").child("Bakery").child("Cake").child("Almond_Cake")
    AlmondSnap.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let almondRate = snapshot.value as! String
            self.cakes[0].cakeRates = almondRate

            print("\(almondRate)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.cakes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.cakeImage.image = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeImages
    cell.cakeEngLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeEngNames
    cell.cakeUrLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeUrNames
    cell.cakeRateLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeRates
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: it is defined in snapshot  {...................}

Comment: yeah but you are using it in instance variable without any declaration of almondRate

Comment: how can i declare it sir,

Comment: ok sir let me try once

Comment: sir would you like to update question with correct things

Comment: it gives same error sir, where should i declare that inside snapshot or in main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the block variable outside the block, also instead of adding multiple array you need to use one array of custom type object.

```
struct Cake {
    var cakeEngName: String
    var cakeUrName: String
    var cakeImage: UIImage
    var cakeRate: String
}
```

Now create the array struct Cake object like `[Cake]` access that array.

```
var cakes = [Cake(cakeEngNames: "almond Cake", cakeUrName: "badam cake", cakeImage: UIImage(named:"Maru")!, cakeRate: ""),
             Cake(cakeEngNames: "Jelly Cake", cakeUrName: "jeli ka cake", cakeImage: UIImage(named:"spices")!, cakeRate: "45")]
```

Now when you get response access the first object from array and set the rate of it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let AlmondSnap = ref.child("Karachi").child("Bakery").child("Cake").child("Almond_Cake")
    AlmondSnap.observeSingleEvent(
        of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let almondRate = snapshot.value as! String
            self.cakes[0].cakeRate = almondRate
            print("\(almondRate)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.cakes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.cakeImage.image = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeImage
    cell.cakeEngLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeEngName
    cell.cakeUrLabs.text = self.cakes[indexPath.row].cakeUrName
    cell.cakeRateLabs.text = self.cake[indexPath.row].cakeRate
    return cell
}
```

Comment: cell.cakeImage.image = cakeImages[indexPath.row] gives error

Comment: a huge thanx Nirav D but cell.cakeImage.image = cakeImages[indexPath.row] gives error

Comment: @Xcodian Now you need to use cakes array like this way `cell.cakeImage.image = cakes[indexPath.row].cakeImage` same goes for other

Comment: ok sir and numberofrowsinsection     return cakeEngNames.count gives error

Comment: @Xcodian Simply access `cakes` array in all places  so it is like `cakes.count`

Comment: @Xcodian Check the edited answer and access simply `cakes` array in all the places.

Comment: @Xcodian reload the `tableView` in observe block check the edited answer.

Comment: thankyou soooo mcuh sir how can i prevent memory warnings

Comment: memory warnibg is running and consuming yupto 30mb

Comment: Using array of struct doesn't cause you memory warning you are getting this warning for some different reasons

Comment: Ok sir, please see updated question, how can i retrieve all the child values of "Cake" to cakeRateLabs.. seeking a help thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xcodian Don't get you what is your question here.

Comment: Update: Retrieve all child values of "cake" to cakeRateLabs just like you retrieved a single value of a single cake, like that  help me to retrieve all the values of cakes from firebase to cakeratelabs : I have updated code below

Comment: @Xcodian You want all the cake child data with name and rate?

Comment: Help me to retrieveall rates of child "Cake" only

Comment: @Xcodian Show your firebase structure and if possible add new question with more detail and post the link here I will check that.

Comment: here is the link sir, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646255/retrieve-all-child-value-to-a-label-in-table-view-cell

Comment: @Xcodian Let me check that